# Passing params from one model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, form-helpers

I'm trying to pass params from one model to another when creating that other model.

For example, when you are listing out all users each user has this link to create a new post:

```
<%= link_to "create", new_post_path %>
```

When that link is clicked and you are redirected to the new_post_path I want to be able to display the name from the user as the value in the name input field.

```
<%= form_for @post method: "post" do |p| %>
  <%= p.label :post_name %>
  <%= p.text_field :post_name, :value => #USER NAME HERE#  %>
  <%= p.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Ideas???

Comment: Association between user and post ?

Comment: Post belongs_to User

Comment: <%= p.text_field :post_name, :value => @post.user.name  %>

Comment: Got it work thanks for everyone's help.  I passed the user id as a param when redirecting to the new_post_path and in the form I had the value be @user.name.  I also changed the controller to be fingind be user_id and not id, which I had before.